# Mongoose inserts document without properties

Tags: node.js, mongoose

MongoDB inserts document without properties(look at the bottom of the post to see how my collection looks like).I'm using postman to test my db when I try to insert the following:

```
{
    "username":"JohnDoe",
    "password" : "123456"   
}
```

I'm building a MEAN stack application.Also, I noticed if I set the properties to be required, postman tells me that it Failed to register user. That's why I comment it out, but even without it and getting a postive response I still get empty documents in my collection.

Postman tells me:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "User registered"
}
```

My user.js file

```
 const bcrypt = require ('bcryptjs');
    const config = require ('../config/database');

    //UserSchema

    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({            
        username: {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        }

    });

    const User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

    //To user function outside
    module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
        User.findById(id,callback);
    }

    module.exports.getUserByUsername= function(username, callback){
        const query = {username: username}
        User.findOne (query,callback);
    }

    User.addUser = function (newUser, callback) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>{
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {

                newUser.password = hash;
                newUser.save(callback);
            });
        });
    }
```

My users.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../modules/user');

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  let newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
    } else {
      res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    }
  });
});    

module.exports = router;
```

What I see in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5937b36bafdd733088cb27d0"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: You are trying to define static methods for something you should be using instance methods for. You are also doing it wrong anyway. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm new at this. What do you mean to be using instance methods? i saw this but it wasn't very clear http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about what is [mongoose statics and methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html).

In User model you should be declaring the functions as methods and statics based on the way you want it.

```
const bcrypt = require ('bcryptjs');
const config = require ('../config/database');

//UserSchema

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({            
    username: {
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        //required: true
    }

});


//To user function outside
UserSchema.statics.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id,callback);
}

UserSchema.statics.getUserByUsername= function(username, callback){
    const query = {username: username}
    User.findOne (query,callback);
}

UserSchema.methods.addUser = function (callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>{
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {

            this.password = hash;
            this.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

exports.User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

In your controller user file, you should use addUser with your instance of the User model not on the Model you exporting. Check below..

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../modules/user');

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  let newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  newUser.addUser(function(err, user) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
    } else {
      res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    }
  });
});    

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. from postman: TypeError: User is not a constructor
    at router.post (C:\Users\pato\Desktop\MEANblog\routes\users.js:9:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\pato\Desktop\MEANblog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Comment: Make sure you are requiring it correctly with right path `const User = require('../modules/user');`